# Passing a clist to a command from a property list

Tags: macros, expl3

I have a command that takes a comma delimited list and does stuff with it. I would like to store a set of these lists using the `expl3` property lists. Here's a simple version of the problem. My basic command works, but when I try to use a list retrieved from the property list, it hangs and I don't understand why. (Uncomment the call to `\mylist` in the `\fromprop` command to see the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_mylist_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_mylist_clist {#1}
    \int_step_inline:nn {4}{
    \clist_pop:NN \l_mylist_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
    \l_tmpa_tl\par
    }}
\prop_new:N \l_myprop_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_myprop_prop {
    A =  {1,2,3,4},
    B =  {1,1,2,2},
    C =  {1,1,1,1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fromprop}{m}{
    \prop_get:NnN \l_myprop_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
    \l_tmpb_tl
%   \mylist{\l_tmpb_tl}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mylist{1,2,3,4}
\fromprop{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would probably use something like `\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}{
 \exp_args:NNo\seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_mylist_seq {#1} 
 \int_step_inline:nn {4}{\seq_item:Nn\l_mylist_seq{##1}\par}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to apply `\mylist` to the bottle, not to the wine inside.

Complex commands using `expl3` code should be split between the “user's level” and the “programmer's level”.

You can therefore generate suitable variants of the programmer's level function.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_mylist_clist
\prop_new:N \l_myprop_prop

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_myprop_prop {
    A =  {1,2,3,4},
    B =  {1,1,2,2},
    C =  {1,1,1,1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}
  {
    \alan_mylist:n { #1 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alan_mylist:n
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_mylist_clist {#1}
    \int_step_inline:nn {4}
      {
        \clist_pop:NN \l_mylist_clist \l_tmpa_tl 
        \l_tmpa_tl\par
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alan_mylist:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand{\fromprop}{m}
  {
    \prop_get:NnN \l_myprop_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
    \alan_mylist:V \l_tmpb_tl
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mylist{1,2,3,4}

\fromprop{A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can see the issue with this test document:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_mylist_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_mylist_clist {#1}
    \show \l_mylist_clist % <---- HERE
    \int_step_inline:nn {4}{
    \clist_pop:NN \l_mylist_clist \l_tmpa_tl
    \show \l_tmpa_tl % <---- HERE
    \l_tmpa_tl\par
    }}
\prop_new:N \l_myprop_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_myprop_prop {
    A =  {1,2,3,4},
    B =  {1,1,2,2},
    C =  {1,1,1,1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fromprop}{m}{
    \prop_get:NnN \l_myprop_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
    \l_tmpb_tl
    \mylist{\l_tmpb_tl}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mylist{1,2,3,4}
\fromprop{A}
\end{document}
```

which gives this output:

```
> \l_mylist_clist=macro:
->1,2,3,4.

> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->1.

[...]

> \l_mylist_clist=macro:
->\l_tmpb_tl .

> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->\l_tmpb_tl .

> \l_tmpa_tl=macro:
->\q_no_value .
```

The issue here is that you're setting a `clist` to a single element containing `\l_tmpb_tl`. If you pop a 1-element `clist` 4 times, you'll eventually get an empty value, represented in expl3 by the quark `\q_no_value`. Then, you typeset this quark, which tries to expand it, leading to an infinite loop. From the documentation:

> Quarks are control sequences (and in fact, token lists) that expand to
> themselves and should therefore never be executed directly in the
> code. This would result in an endless loop!

To fix this, I'd suggest something like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \mylist_helper:n {
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } {
        ##1\par
    }
}
\cs_set_eq:NN \mylist \mylist_helper:n
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \mylist_helper:n { V }

\prop_new:N \l_myprop_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_myprop_prop {
    A =  {1,2,3,4},
    B =  {1,1,2,2},
    C =  {1,1,1,1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fromprop}{m}{
    \prop_get:NnN \l_myprop_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
    \l_tmpb_tl
    \mylist_helper:V \l_tmpb_tl
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mylist{1,2,3,4}
\fromprop{A}
\end{document}
```

Here, we correctly expand the variable in `\fromprop`, and we avoid accidentally going past the end of the `clist` by using the builtin iterator.

---

**Edit**

> Thanks but this doesn't capture one basic property of the code that I
> need to preserve, specifically the the `\mylist` macro itself, which
> (for reasons not relevant here) can't be implemented with just a
> simple mapping function. So is there a solution that keeps `\mylist`
> intact and does what I want?

> So what I'm looking for is a way to get the output of `\fromprop` to
> behave exactly as if I had typed the list directly.

A minimally-changed solution:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_mylist_clist
\NewDocumentCommand{\mylist}{m}{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_mylist_clist {#1}
    \int_step_inline:nn {4}{
    \clist_pop:NN \l_mylist_clist \l_tmpa_tl
    \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_tmpa_tl { % <--- CHANGED
        \l_tmpa_tl\par
    }
    }}
\prop_new:N \l_myprop_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_myprop_prop {
    A =  {1,2,3,4},
    B =  {1,1,2,2},
    C =  {1,1,1,1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fromprop}{m}{
    \prop_get:NnN \l_myprop_prop {#1} \l_tmpb_tl
    \l_tmpb_tl
    \exp_args:NV \mylist \l_tmpb_tl % <--- CHANGED
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\mylist{1,2,3,4}
\fromprop{A}
\end{document}
```

This solution uses `\exp_args:NV` to expand the value of `\l_tmpb_tl` before it is used by `\mylist`. It also uses `\quark_if_no_value:NF` to prevent accidentally expanding a quark if the end of the list is reached (this part isn't strictly necessary, but it's probably a good idea).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't capture one basic property of the code that I need to preserve, specifically the the `\mylist` macro itself, which (for reasons not relevant here) can't be implemented with just a simple mapping function. So is there a solution that keeps `\mylist` intact and does what I want?

Comment: So what I'm looking for is a way to get the output of `\fromprop` to behave exactly as if I had typed the list directly.

Comment: @AlanMunn You can do that with a simple `\exp_args:NV`. You probably also want to use `\quark_if_no_value:NTF` to make sure that you don't accidentally expand a quark. See the edit.